# Markdown toc disappears on save since I installed ALE linter

Tags: plugin-ale, plugin-vim-rmarkdown

I am using the markdown extension [plasticboy/vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) to navigate inside large markdown files:

> " :Toc : create a quickfix vertical window navigable table of contents with the headers."

[image]

Since I In installed the [ALE linter](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale), the content of the quick fix window disappears after I save the markdown file.

[image]

When I disable ALE, it works fine and the TOC content remains visible at all times, even after file save. 
I can disable ale temporarily in a buffer this way:

```
let b:ale_enabled = 0
```

But how Can I get plasticboy/vim-markdown to continue working properly when ALE is activated?

Comment: Ale is overwriting the quickfix list; you’ll need to tell ale to use the location list instead

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Actually ALE uses the loclist by default... But see this FAQ for variables to control both lists: https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/blob/master/README.md#5xi-how-can-i-use-the-quickfix-list-instead-of-the-loclist

Comment: @filbranden yeah I see that; I read quickfix in the Q and assumed. Funnily, the quoted doc is wrong (as proven by the screenshot, which says loclist!).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I actually think it's saying `toclist()`... ?!

Comment: And yeah looks like vim-markdown uses loclist indeed: https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/master/ftplugin/markdown.vim#L360

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of a more elegant fix, I disabled ALE for markdown files as explained in [ALE issue 371](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale/issues/371), by adding this to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Disable ale for some file extensions 
let g:ale_pattern_options = {          
\   '.*\.md$': {'ale_enabled': 0},     
\   '.*\.Rmd$': {'ale_enabled': 0},    
\}
```